# In which situations should I use knockout.js?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

Guys I want to know when to use knockout.js . For which problems can knockout.js leverage javascript?
Basically I want to know for which type of apps should I be using knockout.js and what are the advantages and disadvantages of using it?

Comment: Your question is **very** open-ended, can you improve it?

Comment: The first lines of the [Knockout JS documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/introduction.html) will give you a hint.

Comment: @all, it's a shame that this was closed. IMHO it's a valid question. With an MVC lib round every corner it's justified to ask what the deal is.

Comment: Watch this [presentation of Steve Sanderson](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/TechDays/Techdays-2012-the-Netherlands/2159) and learn the basics

Comment: @999 A lot of the problems with open ended, comparison type questions are dealt with here: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/gorilla-vs-shark/.  A better question would be along the lines of "I want to accomplish x with a single page application, can knockout.js provide the tools for that"...

Comment: I think I deserve a vote up on this . I edited the question.

Comment: @teahupoo. You still haven't made it un-open ended. See the faq: http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Comment: @Tyrsius how do I do that. Could not find it on the FAQ

Comment: @teahupoo dude, I linked to it. Its right here http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Comment: Move this to programmers.SE.